# How to delete collections from the RigidBodyWorld list?

Tags: rigidbody

I can't find the possibility to empty the collection list, how do you do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found out how to do it, just go inside
Outliner -> OrphanData -> Collections**

[image]

[image]

And click on the power button on the right

Save, close and restart blender.

I thought it was a bug, and thanks to everyone for trying to answer!